# Failed to retrieve "console font-size" using "GetCurrentConsoleFont()" in "Windows XP"?

Tags: c, winapi, console-application, mingw32

I compiled this code without any errors and warnings with GCC mingw32:

```
#define WINVER 0x0500
#include <windows.h>
HWND StdHandle = GetStdHandle (STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
CONSOLE_FONT_INFO GETFONT;
GetCurrentConsoleFont (StdHandle, FALSE, &GETFONT);
if (GETFONT.dwFontSize.X != 8 || GETFONT.dwFontSize.Y != 12)
  printf ("Font-Size is not 8 x 12");
else
  printf("Font-Size is 8 x 12");
```

It runs perfectly in Windows 7.

But, when it runs in Windows XP and I adjust the console font-size to "8 x 12", `GETFONT.dwFontSize.X` always equals 80, and `GETFONT.dwFontSize.Y` always equals 25.

Then, I added

```
DWORD ErrorCode = GetLastError();
```

And, it returns [`0x0` (ERROR_SUCCESS(:The operation completed successfully.))](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Why it always get the wrong value when using [GetCurrentConsoleFont](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683176%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in Windows XP?

Comment: You are not performing any error checking at all. You need to check the return values of the functions you call. Don't just call `GetLastError`. Only do that if the MSDN docs say it has meaning.

Comment: OT (?): To target XP use: `#define WINVER 0x0501`! `0x0500` is Windows 2000, for which `GetCurrentConsoleFont()` is **not** available. For reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6sehtctf.aspx

Comment: @alk THX for your advice about changing `0x0500` to `0x0501`. And I have just found the perfect solution to this problem:

Comment: Did this change solved the issue?

Comment: @alk Not but Thanks. Where can I post the solution to this issue? Is it suitable to answer my own question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
BOOL WINAPI GetCurrentConsoleFont (HANDLE hConsoleOutput, BOOL bMaximumWindow, PCONSOLE_FONT_INFO lpConsoleCurrentFont);
COORD WINAPI GetConsoleFontSize (HANDLE hConsoleOutput, DWORD nFont);

CONSOLE_FONT_INFO GETFONT;
GetCurrentConsoleFont (StdHandle, FALSE, &GETFONT);
COORD Fontsize = GetConsoleFontSize (StdHandle, GETFONT.nFont);
SHORT Font_X = Fontsize.X;
SHORT Font_Y = Fontsize.Y;
if (Font_X != 8 || Font_Y != 12)
{
     printf ("Font-Size is not 8 x 12");
}
```

Comment: Please try to explain this rather than just throwing code at us. Why have you added this when it seems to offer nothing more than edokan's answer? And please do heed what I said about error checking. You don't do any!

Comment: @David Heffernan Oh, I know that. But..., I just have learned C Language for 1 month, and Windows API for 3 days. And...I am just a 13-year-old student. Please give me several days to enhance the quality of this code. Thanks for your advice about error checking

Answer (score 2):

MSDN documentation on CONSOLE_FONT_INFO says

> To obtain the size of the font, pass the font index to the GetConsoleFontSize function.

Comment: But, why cannot just use `GetCurrentConsoleFont()`? It also can get the value of font-size by passing a pointer to a CONSOLE_FONT_INFO structure. Doesn't it?

Comment: I don't know. Interesting thing is that both pages for `CONSOLE_FONT_INFO` and `GetConsoleFontSize` says the exact same thing. You can open a ticket on MS connect or you can just write an if and call it a day.